# Python - Iterating through rows of excel files with Pandas

Tags: python, excel

I have problem with **iterating through rows** in **excel file**.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import json

for file in os.listdir("./python_files"):
    if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
        df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join("./python_files", file)) 
        CRD_Array = df.iloc[:,1].values
        for single_CRD in CRD_Array:           
            with open("{}.json".format(single_CRD), 'w') as json_file:
                row_iterator = 0
                data = {}
                data['header']=[]
                data['header'].append({'Organization CRD#':  '{}'.format(df.iloc[row_iterator,1])})
                json.dump(data, json_file)
                row_iterator = row_iterator + 1
```

**How u can see my script is**

1. Reading files from `python_files` folder
2. Then it's reading second column with `CRD` number which returns an array of `CRDs`
3. Then it's looping `CRD` array
4. In that loop It's trying to save `.json` file with "hedar" field

**What I get in output now**

File name **`172081.json`**

```
{"header": [{"Organization CRD#": "172081"}
```

File name **`534123.json`**

```
{"header": [{"Organization CRD#": "172081"}
```

File name **`184521.json`**

```
{"header": [{"Organization CRD#": "172081"}
```

I looks like `df.iloc [row_iterator, 1]` isn't changing row property despite adding +1 for each loop repeat

Can somebody help?

Edit:
Excel file example-

[image]

What I want to achieve

File name **`172081.json`**

```
{"header": [{"Organization CRD#": "172081"}
```

File name **`534123.json`**

```
{"header": [{"Organization CRD#": "534123"}
```

File name **`184521.json`**

```
{"header": [{"Organization CRD#": "184521"}
```

Comment: Give a sample of the data, raw and your target.

Answer (score 2):

In the for loop you are increasing the row_iterator, but in the first line after open you always set it back to 0. You need to take that line out from the loop. Like this:

```
row_iterator = 0

for single_CRD in CRD_Array: 
          
    with open("{}.json".format(single_CRD), 'w') as json_file:
       data = {}
       data['header']=[]
       data['header'].append({'Organization CRD#': '{}'.format(df.iloc[row_iterator,1])})
       json.dump(data, json_file)
       row_iterator = row_iterator + 1
```

Comment: Omg, I was thinking how to solve this problem for 30 minutes, I didn't see that I'm assigning 0 to `row_iterator`  every time when loop in executed. Ty so much :D

Comment: You are welcome:) I also suggest avoid this much nesting in your code, because it will get hard to understand. Eg. you could do: 
```if not file.endswith(...):  continue``` then ```df = ...```